# How do I access both the typing from the API call?

Tags: python, json

So my current code looks like this:

```
response = requests.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/palkia").json()

    data = response["types"][1]
    print(data)
```

Write now it only give the dictionary of the second typing, how can I get the just the name of the to typing's as the result

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean.  It isn't clear what you mean by 'second typing' and 'to typing'.

Comment: `for t in response["types"]: print(t["type"]["name"])`?

Answer (score 0):

`response["types"]` is a list of dictionaries, and by indexing it with `[1]` you access the second element. To get the names for all elements in `response["types"]`, you could e.g. do

```
data = [e["type"]["name"] for e in response["types"]]
```